# Escaped quote as the value of a field crashes my sql script

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I have the following dml sql (generated by mysql wb):

```
INSERT INTO `status_need` VALUES (1,1,1,'famille cherchant une autre famille (pour garde partagée ou sortie d\'école)'),(2,1,2,'famille cherchant professionnelle de la garde d\'enfants'),(3,2,1,'professionnelle de la garde d\'enfants cherchant enfants à garder');
```

When I run it from java, it raises an error probably because of the apostrophe/quote within the value of the field.

I am not sure why that is because the quote is escaped by a backslash and what is more, this SQL was generated by mysql itself.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I use Unitils so I can't control the way the scripts are called - using PreparedStatements for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your Java code has a string literal that looks like this:

```
"INSERT INTO `status_need` VALU...ie d\'écol..."
```

?

The reason that doesn't work is that in Java, inside a string literal, `\'` means `'`. You need to escape the backslash `\` by writing `\\` instead:

```
"INSERT INTO `status_need` VALU...ie d\\'écol..."
```

(Or, as danihp says, you can sidestep the issue by writing `''` instead of `\'`: MySQL supports both ways of escaping a single-quote inside a single-quoted string.)

Comment: I wish I could control the escape characters but Mysql Workbench administrator does not seem to allow for this.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) documentation:

```
There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:

A “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.

A “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.

Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”).

A “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “"” inside a string quoted with “'” needs no special treatment.
```

But the **right answer** is that you should look for a way that java make this for you. Somethink like real_escape php function. See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is mostly use prepared statements. You may refer to below link
http://lists.mysql.com/java/5469

Also replacing all occurrences manually may have strange results. For this please refer to below blog explantion.

http://www.bartbusschots.ie/blog/?p=141